# Node.js & Mustache.js: How to separate server-side rendering than client-side mustache templating?

Tags: html, node.js, mustache, server-side-rendering, client-side-templating

I try to render `second.html` with server-side after validating a form in `home.html`, then keep mustache.js to template (update) parts from `second.html` as user validates new form in it (multiple times).

problem: html renders the parameters from server-side but sees parameters from mustache as empty strings

I knew that mustache can work for both server and client side but I didn't use mustache in the server files

server-side file

```js
var serverSideParameter = 'server'
res.render('chat.html', { serverSideParameter })
```

client-side file

```js
var clientSideParameter = 'client'
const html = Mustache.render(Template, { clientSideParameter })
document.querySelector('#Container').innerHTML = html;
```

html file

```html
<div id="Container"></div>

<p> {{serverSideParameter}} </p>

<script id="Template" type="text/html">
  <p> {{clientSideParameter}} </p>
</script>
```

output:

```html
<div id="Container">
  <p></p>
</div>

<p>server</p>
```

Desired output:

```html
<div id="Container">
  <p>client</p>
</div>

<p>server</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution**

define them into the client-side js file

`res.send()` didn't work for me